# How to query multiple partitions of a Firebase Analytics events table in Big Query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am querying from the Firebase Analytics tables.

The table I am using has a partition for each day. Here are some examples of the various daily partitions:

```
arm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_20180628
rm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_20180627
arm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_20180629
```

Essentially I am asking how to query the .all (every partition) of the table. Ie the partition from every single date recorded.  Would also be great to query n days ago.

I have gone through BQ documentation on partitioned tables and the regular syntax seems to not work as intended. I have also noticed that normal partitioned tables have just the date after the table name as opposed to ".events_[date]" as shown in the example above.

Currently I am just unioning every partition which is extremely long and obviously unscalable. Anyone have experience with querying these tables?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Answer (score 9):

To query events for all days use a wildcard:

```
FROM arm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_*
```

To query events for a particular month or year use wildcards and leave the month or year prefix, e.g.:

```
FROM arm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_201806*
```

or

```
FROM arm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_2018*
```

To set an arbitrary partition filter use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` column:

```
FROM arm_studio.analytics_177892322.events_*
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180627' and '20180630'
```